# Запуск скрипта javascript во время загрузки страницы и пагинация

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

Всем привет. Есть страница с таблицей и **пагинацией**. Пагинация срабатывает во время отработки скрипта с фильтром, но мне необходимо чтобы пагинация происходила во время первой загрузки страницы. Как запустить скрипт автоматически во время первой загрузки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function pagination() {
  ...
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() { pagination(); });
```